# Passar array via post em Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

Estou precisando passar um *array* via *POST*, tentei da seguinte forma:

```
  const params = new URLSearchParams();
  params.append('pagamentos', this.variavel_array);
  axios.post('grava_pedido_pdv.php', params);
```

A variável `variavel_array` contém o valor `{'nome' : 'victor', 'cod' : 1}`, contudo, no console visualizo como "**pagamentos: [object Object]**"  e não consigo ler esse valor no *PHP*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[object Object]` é o retorno do método toString() de um objeto. Para enviar o objeto no formato JSON você tem que enviar `JSON.stringify(variavel_array)` mas melhor ainda é transformar seu objeto em uma string de parâmetros HTML.
JavaScript não tem essa função nativa, mas você pode criar um helper:

```
function toParam(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(a,k){a.push(k+'='+encodeURIComponent(obj[k]));return a},[]).join('&')
}
```